# OpenWebkitSharp for .NET -- any trick for getting Javascript to work with it in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, open-webkit-sharp

I am using the OpenWebkitSharp browser in a VB.NET project. What I am trying to do is use **WebkitBrowser1.Navigate** to display some HTML in the browser "on the fly". This works great for basic HTML, but Javascript does not appear to work at all in this scenario. For example, I have...

```
WebKitBrowser1.DocumentText = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>alert('This is an alert'); </script></head><body><p>This is some text</p></body></html>"
```

The body text appears just fine, but there is never a Javascript alert. I made sure that Javascript is enabled in the Webkit browser, so that's not the issue.

If I use the Navigate method to display a local page that contains Javascript (ie **WebkitBrowser1.Navigate("path/to/local/file")**, then the Javascript works perfectly. But it doesn't work at all when setting the HTML using **WebKitBrowser1.DocumentText**.

For this particular project, I need to generate the HTML code and display it "on the fly", so I can't use **WebKitBrowser1.Navigate**. I have to use **WebkitBrowser1.DocumentText** instead (or something similar).

Any ideas?

Or might there be a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation recently, and while I'm still looking for that solution that allows what you're describing, here's what I decided to do as a workaround:

-Save HTML to temporary file
-Load temp file into WebKit control on form.

I'm considering making my own modifications to OpenWebKitSharp however, to see if I can make this happen.  Basically, it seems like HTML loaded through DocumentText follows a different render path than loaded through Navigate.